# Reading subsequent response from a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to read bytes into chars from a server which is not maintained by me. Here am the client. My issue is am not getting the required response from the request sent to the server. From my understanding, to detect the end of a message, there are three common ways:

*Closing the connection at the end of the message.

*Putting the length of the message before the data itself

*Using a separator; some value which will never occur in the normal data

So this what I have done so far.Am using sockets to achieve writing to the server like this:

```
Socket outgoing = new Socket(Host, Port);

String request = "GET http://www.firtRequest.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.firstRequest.com\r\n\r\n" + "GET http://www.secondRequest.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.secondRequest.com\r\n\r\n";
outgoing.getOutputStream().write(request.getBytes());
outgoing.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Using `getInputStream()` to read from the socket server,I should get two reponses back but the second response carries a html tag which from my understanding isn't part of the resonse so am guessing am not reading till the end of the stream for the first request sent to the server or am not reading the reponses properly altogether.

Output1:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: mon,24 Aug 2015 09:02:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 42
```

Output2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C"
  ....
<head>
 ....
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Here is my read method in which am trying to detect the end of the stream using `"\r\n\r\n"` tag in the reponse or when the stream hits -1.

```
public static String ReadStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        int rdL = inputStream.read();
        if (rdL == -1) {
            break;
        }
        // Convert the bytes read into characters
        builder.append((char) rdL);
        if (builder.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") != -1) {
            // EOS detected
            break;
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Any pointers to what am doing wrong to be getting that html tag? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a little bit more, what html tag are you talking about ?!!

Comment: @QuakeCore Usually when someone writes two request, two responses should be gotten. In my second response, am getting a html tag with the response.

Answer (score 0):

> there are three common ways:

There's only one 'common way' with HTTP, and that is to implement RFC 2616 correctly. You haven't made the slightest attempt here. Look it up. But there's no good reason to try to implement HTTP yourself when `HttpURLConnection` already exists, not to mention numerous third-party HTTP APIs.

Comment: I metioned three ways of detecting the end of stream from a socket. Correct me if am wrong stating otherwise from the documentation plus your  answer doesn't actually solve my question.

Comment: @codeFreak for sockets generically there may be "three common ways" but **for HTTP/1.1** two EOLs (canonically `\r\n\r\n`) ends the *header* but neither it nor any other separator is used for the body; connection close can't be used with multiple requests and you are doing multiple requests; so the only options are prefix lengths, and HTTP/1.1 has *two* ways of doing prefix lengths (traditional content-length and new optional chunked), both described in detail in the RFC. If you want to communicate using HTTP/1.1 you must implement HTTP/1.1 -- or use something that does.

Comment: @dave_thompson thanks a million. Your comment actually answers my question. +1